# Better way to do SELECT with GROUP BY

Tags: sql, mysql, performance, join, group-by

Hi i've wrote a query that works:

```
SELECT `comments`.* FROM `comments` 
RIGHT JOIN (SELECT MAX( id ) AS id, core_id, topic_id 
FROM comments GROUP BY core_id, topic_id order by id desc) comm 
ON comm.id = comments.id LIMIT 10
```

I want know if it is possible (and how) to rewrite it to get better performance.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Method 1 - improving the original query

I am pretty sure that in this case is an **`INNER JOIN` will suffice**, there is no reason to do a `RIGHT JOIN` (if an `id` exists in `comm` it will also exists in `comments`).  `INNER JOIN`s **can result in [better performance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1810465/left-join-faster-or-inner-join-faster).**

Moreover, you really want to push the `LIMIT 10` inside `comm` (incidentally, keeping it together with the `ORDER BY`):

- for one, *not* keeping `LIMIT 10` and `ORDER BY` together will *not* get you the ten most recently posted-to topics (the ordering of the `comm` subquery will not necessarily be preserved into the final result which you are `LIMIT`ing.)
- additionally, enforcing the `LIMIT` inside the innermost, aggregate subquery will encourage cost-based optimizers to favour [nested loops](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_(SQL)#Nested_loops) (10, to be exact) over [hash](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_(SQL)#Hash_join) or [merge joins](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_(SQL)#Merge_join) (the 10 nested loops being **by far the fastest** for any respectably-sized `comments` table.)

So, your query should be rewritten as:

```
SELECT `comments`.* FROM `comments` 
INNER JOIN (
 SELECT MAX( id ) AS id, core_id, topic_id 
 FROM comments
 GROUP BY core_id, topic_id
 ORDER BY id DESC
 LIMIT 10
) comm 
ON comm.id = comments.id
ORDER BY comments.id
```

Finally, **use [`EXPLAIN`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/explain.html)** to see what the query is doing.  Do not forget to check that you have created an index on `comments.id` to help with the `JOIN` nested loops.

#### Method 2 - a different approach

Note that while the above query could still be faster than your original query, **the innermost `comm` subquery may still turn out to be a significant bottleneck** if it results in a full table scan of `comments`.  This really depends on how smart the database is when it sees `GROUP BY`, `ORDER BY` and `LIMIT` together.

If `EXPLAIN` indicates that the subquery is doing a table scan, then you can try **a combination of SQL and application-level logic** to get the best performance **assuming that I have understood your requirement correctly and that you want to identify the ten most recent comments posted in ten different topics**:

```
# pseudo-code
core_topics_map = { }
command = "SELECT * FROM comments ORDER BY id DESC;"
command.execute
# iterate over the result set, betting that we will be able to break
#  early, bringing only a handful of rows over from the database server
while command.fetch_next_row do
  # have we identified our 10 most recent topics?
  if core_topics_map.size >= 10 then
    command.close
    break
  else
    core_topic_key = pair(command.field('core_id'), command.field('topic_id'))
    if not defined?(core_topics_map[core_topic_key]) then
      core_topics_map[core_topic_key] = command.field('id')
    end
  end
done
# sort our 10 topics in reverse chronological order
sort_by_values core_topics_map
```

In most cases (that is, provided that your application's database driver does not attempt to buffer all rows into memory for you before giving you back control from `execute`), the above will only fetch a handful of rows, always using an index, with no table scans involved.

#### Method 3 - a hybrid approach

If ten seconds ago I knew what the ten most recent comments were, can I be smart about it when I ask the question again later on?  **Unless comments can be deleted from the database**, then the answer is yes, because I know that, when I ask the question again, all comment IDs will be greatly than or equal to the oldest comment ID I got in my last query.

I can therefore rewrite the innermost query to be **much, much more selective** using an additional condition, `WHERE id >= :last_lowest_id`:

```
SELECT `comments`.* FROM `comments` 
INNER JOIN (
 SELECT MAX( id ) AS id, core_id, topic_id 
 FROM comments
 WHERE id >= :last_lowest_id
 GROUP BY core_id, topic_id
 ORDER BY id DESC
 LIMIT 10
) comm 
ON comm.id = comments.id
ORDER BY comments.id
```

When you run the query for the very first time, use `0` for `:last_lowest_id`.  The query will return up to 10 rows, in descending order.  Inside your application, **put aside the `id` of the last row**, and reuse its value as `:last_lowest_id` the next time you run the query, and repeat (again, put aside the `id` of the last row returned by the latest query etc.)  This will essentially make the query **incremental, and extremely fast**.

Example:

- running the query for the first time with `:last_lowest_id` set to `0`

  - returns 10 rows with IDs: `129, 100, 99, 88, 83, 79, 78, 75, 73, 70`
  - save `70`
- running the query for the second time with `:last_lowest_id` set to `70`

  - returns 10 rows with IDs: `130, 129, 100, 99, 88, 83, 79, 78, 75, 73`
  - save `73`
- etc.

#### Method 4 - yet another approach

If you expect to perform `SELECT ... ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 10` much more often than `INSERT`s into the `comments` table, consider putting a bit more work into the `INSERT` to make the `SELECT` faster.  Thus, you can add an indexed `updated_at` column to your `topics` etc. table, and whenever you `INSERT` a comment into the `comments` table consider also updating the corresponding topic's `updated_at` value to `NOW()`.  You can then easily select the 10 most recently updated topics (a simple and short index scan on `updated_at` returning 10 rows), inner joining with the `comments` table to get the `MAX(id)` for those 10 topics (infinitely more efficient than getting `MAX(id)` for *all* topics before picking the ten greatest, like in the original and Method 1), then inner joining again on `comments` to get the rest of thecolumn values for those 10.

I expect overall performance of Method 4 to be comparable with Methods 2 and 3.  Method 4 will have to be used if you need to get arbitrary topics (e.g. by paginating them, `LIMIT 10 OFFSET 50`) or if topics or comments can be removed (no changes necessary to support topic removal; to support comment removal properly then the topic's `updated_at` should be updated on both comment `INSERT` and `DELETE` with the `created_at` value of the latest non-deleted comment for the topic.)