# Using left joins in views in place of slower inner joins VS creating indexes for views

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, indexing, left-join, inner-join

It is known that LEFT joins are way faster than INNER joins. On the other hand, SQL Server prohibits to create indexes for those views that use left joins in their code.

Now, I have a view with a non-indexed column (of type nchar) which is quite often in where-queries. I am going to put an index on this column, but it turns out that I can do it only at the price of replacing all my left joins to inner joins.

Is the benefit of indexes worth it ?

Comment: "LEFT joins are way faster than INNER joins". Where did you get it from? In any case, just try both variants and measure the performance of your system.

Comment: Well, this is not always the case - I mean, better performance of LEFT JOIN as opposed to INNER JOIN. I know that from my own experience as well as from discussions here (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1810465/left-join-faster-or-inner-join-faster). But in some cases, it is.

Comment: *"It is known that LEFT joins are way faster than INNER joins"* > My BS detector just went off into overdrive. If you claim that, include a link with a formal proof of that. You won't find it. If you need to JOIN finding matches that exist in both left and right side tables, INNER JOIN is the best you are going to get.

Comment: *"Is the benefit of indexes worth it ?"* > You started off with an incorrect assumption, so there is no valid answer to this question.

Comment: Right now I have tested that on a view containing 347275 rows. With LEFT JOIN the entire view is rendered during only 24 seconds, compared to 37 seconds in case of INNER JOIN. It is assumed that all the rows have matches

Comment: Include the VIEW definition in your question, along with all TABLE definitions the VIEW refers to, and an actual execution plan for a select on the VIEW. There is an underlying problem, most likely missing indexes/primary keys. Otherwise it is quite impossible to answer your question.